# How to play sound on all audio devices

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, device

I have a program which is alerting the user. But right now it is only allerting on the default audio device. That is a problem if the user has pluged in a headset but don't wear it. So my question is: "***Is it possible to set the allert sound to all audio devices instead of the default device only?"***

I am programming in c#, wpf and .net 4.0

Right now I am using this code to play the alert sound:

```
private MMDeviceEnumerator devEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
private MMDevice defaultDevice;
```

....

```
defaultDevice = devEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);
```

....

```
defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevel = 1;
```

....

```
alarm.Play();
```

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: I suppose your users might have different requirements, but I know I would be extremely irritated if an application decided it was going to play across all the audio devices on my machine at the same time. (I have regular speakers, a dolby digital output, and a usb headphone/mic connected)

Comment: There is nobody to copy data between devices. As you enumerated them you can start playback on every one in question independently.

Comment: The problem is that a headset/speaker doesn't correspond to a device on many systems. I think a device is more like a audio driver or soundcard. When I plugin my headset the speakers get muted, but the device stays the same.

Comment: I am aware that it will be iritating for the users that all devices are alerting, but that is also the purpurse. :D

Comment: I can't figure out how to play in the speakers only. Can someone please help me? I Need to always play a sound in the computer speakers no matter if a headset is plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to use **EnumAudioEndpoints**. Please visit this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370812%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) then you might get the conception of that.

Comment: ok... but then. How do I play on the computers speakers. Because the default endpoint can also be a headset?

Comment: Do you have an example of how to reach the speakers only (not default device)

Answer (score 0):

What I have found so far this isn't possible in windows vista and later.